# Reading value of an array in another

Tags: arrays

i want to put "brian" in another array $request. How can i read the value of an array in another array ?

```
'USER'=>'$paypal['USER']',
```

Can i do it directly like this ?

```
<?php
    $paypal = array(
            'mail'=>'mail@mail.com',
            'USER'=>'brian',
        );

    $request = array(
                'METHOD'=>'BMCreateButton',
                'VERSION'=>'87',
                'USER'=>'///',
                );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the script as below, i.e modify array once created

```
$request['USER'] = $paypal['USER'];
```

or set it while creating as below

```
$request = array(
    'METHOD'  => 'BMCreateButton',
    'VERSION' => '87',
    'USER'    => $paypal['USER'],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$request = array(
    'METHOD'  => 'BMCreateButton',
    'VERSION' => '87',
    'USER'    => $paypal['USER'],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $paypal = array(
            'mail'=>'mail@mail.com',
            'USER'=>'brian',
        );

    $request = array(
                'METHOD'=>'BMCreateButton',
                'VERSION'=>'87',
                'USER'=>$paypal['USER'] // works
                );
    ?>
```